# How to update ruby on mac version 10.15.5

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

I would like to update the ruby version I have installed from 2.6.3p62 version to 2.7.1

I tried to follow these instructions found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-macos)

Because I was having an issue with Ruby before in the past I thought it would be a good idea to go through the uninstalling portion from that tutorial first.

I tried installing again starting from the first step but when I did `type rbenv` what shows up instead is `rbenv is /usr/local/bin/rbenv`

I'm not sure why that happens but I went ahead to try to install ruby version 2.7.1 and once I get to checking my ruby version doing `ruby -v` it shows `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]` instead of ruby version 2.7.1 which I installed.

I tried `rbenv versions` and what shows up in the console is

```
system
* 2.7.1 (set by /Users/michaeltorres/.rbenv/version)
```

I am not sure what is going on but it seems like a ruby version 2.6.3 is still being detected

Comment: You don't do anything with the system Ruby - `rbenv` sets up shims to use one of the Rubies that you install with it.  Have you set up your shell per the [documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: You need to check that your `PATH` is set correctly. If `rbenv` is not first then other Ruby instances might have priority. `rbenv` has a shim that needs to load, as red points out, so be sure to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a few things, first, let us check what shell you are using

```
echo "$SHELL"
```

Now it depends what file you check for your rbenv staff, if are you getting `/bin/bash or` `/bin/sh` or '/bin/zsh' then first check using nano or vim to see if it has anything related to RBENV, if not then add the following lines as per your shell.

#### for bash

```
vi ~/.bash_profile 
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

#### for Zsh

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

This command is just adding .rbenv you have to restart your terminal/iterm to take effective results.

Now you should have rbenv properly install to make sure it is really installed you can run the following command

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

If it gives you at end all Ok messages than mean you have now everything up. Now use rbenv to install your ruby version, you don't need to uninstall system ruby but you are using rbenv to setup different versions of ruby.  Run following command to check which version of ruby available for installation

```
rbenv install -l
```

Now you have to use the following command to install your ruby version 2.7.1

```
rbenv install 2.7.1
```

Or whatever version you got in its available listing just put same version.

Happy Coding.